# What is meant by Global-warming Potential (GWP)?

Tags: carbon-footprint, greenhouse-gas-emissions

I was under the impression GWP (global-warming potential) is the measure of a gas' impact on global warming, in comparison with CO2.

E.g. methane has a GWP of 86 over 20 years - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global-warming_potential)

Comparing paper and ceramic cups for GWP, [this article](https://www.tcd.ie/GreenPages/documents/refiller_cup_comparison.pdf) (page 24) shows GWP in kilograms. Does this make sense to show GWP in kg? Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post the same question](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/7100/1109) on multiple sites. If you are not sure which site is best to ask a question, try one site first and if you don't get a satisfactory response in a few days then either ask a moderator to migrate the question, or delete the question and try it again on another relevant site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a cosmetic issue. They're just using the language in an idiosyncratic way.

What this particular document means by "GWP" on page 24 is simply the amount of CO<sub>2</sub>-equivalent emissions.

Normally that would just be labelled kgCO<sub>2</sub>e or tCO<sub>2</sub>e for kilogrammes or tonnes of emissions respectively.

Earlier in the same document, they'd used GWP to refer to carbon intensity rates, e.g. on page 16 the global warming potential is given in units of kg CO2-eq./cup - the emissions rate per cup. Again, that's not really GWP, but what I've seen more commonly called the carbon intensity.